# Match everything between HTML tags

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, multiline

I need to match everything between html tags, or if there is another way, get all of the information between the tags out of them.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
<B>stuff here</B>

<B>Changes in the taxicab and <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">for-
hire</FONT>  vehicle industries have resulted in increased competition and  
have had a material adverse effect on our business, financial condition, and 
operations.  </B>


medallions. </P> <P STYLE="margin-top:12pt; margin-bottom:0pt; text-indent:4%; font-size:10pt; font-family:Times New Roman"><B>We borrow money, which magnifies the potential for gain or loss on amounts invested, and may increase the risk of investing in us. </B></P>
```

These are the matches I need to get from this small block:

```
<B>stuff here</B>

<B>Changes in the taxicab and <FONT STYLE="white-space:nowrap">for-
hire</FONT>  vehicle industries have resulted in increased competition and  
have had a material adverse effect on our business, financial condition, and 
operations.  </B>

<B>We borrow money, which magnifies the potential for gain or loss on amounts invested, and may increase the risk of investing in us. </B>
```

Here are a couple of the Regex's I've tried, both do not work to the extent to which I want it to work:

```
re.compile("<[Bb]>[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\-\=\,\.\/\<\?\:\"\;\'\{\}\[\]\|\\\w\d\s]*<\/[Bb]>", re.MULTILINE)
re.compile("<[Bb]>.+<\/[Bb]>", re.MULTILINE)
```

Or is there a better way to do this without Regex?

I'm currently loading the HTML content into a text file to remove the indents

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4 And indeed, since html allows nesting tags inside tags (e.g. divs inside divs)(chomsky type 3 grammar), it cannot be parsed by regex (chomsky type 2 grammar)/

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge I've looked into it, but I'm parsing unstructured HTM (not HTML) and the more advanced regex's I'm using pull out just the bolded text from the website, because it is the only identifier on the entire page. Also I load the HTML content into a text file to remove indents

Comment: There's no difference between HTM and HTML

Comment: @HFBrowning good to know

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern to match everything between the `<B>` tags:

```
 (?s)(?<=<B>).*(?=<\/B>)
```

This uses a positive look ahead (`(?<=<B>)`) and a positive look behind (`(?=<\/B>)`) to match anything in-between the tags.